# Can I disable a certain speaker in the group policy, registry key or a script?

Tags: windows, group-policy, audio

I have a number of users with a microphone called that has also a loudspeaker built in. The microphone is called "Sonic Mic 3". The users don't want to use the loud speakers for the most part.

Is there a way to disable it as a speaker using either

- group policy
- registry key
- command-line?

I know that the speaker can be disabled under Sounds in the Control Panel, but I'd like to avoid having to do that 100 times.

Comment: Normally i'd find the driver file being used and rename or delete it using GPO. But in this case I assume the microphone and speaker are using the same driver file. Can you confirm?

Comment: @spacenomyous Not sure, how could I find out if both use the same driver file?

Answer (score 1):

There's an app written by NirSoft called 'Sound Volume View' which can be launched with various command line switches to do things like this.

[Sound Volume View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/sound_volume_view.html)

I believe you could just create a policy to run something along the lines of:

```
SoundVolumeView.exe /Disable "Sonic Mic 3"
```

You might need to copy the app locally first. That sound endpoint should then be disabled in the control panel 'Sound' applet. Bear in mind though that the device would need to be connected when this was run via policy, or else it would have no effect. Similarly, if you unplugged the device and plugged it back in, it may come back as 'enabled' by default.